# \par\bigskip and the parskip package

Tags: spacing

I read that if one uses the `parskip` package then there is no need to add `\par\bigskip` to separate paragraphs; it is enough to move the new sentence to new line with Enter. That's true but at some locations I'm getting a very big skip although I just made a skip by moving the paragraph to a new line with the Enter button. And if I for example change the `linespread` from `1.8` to `1.6` I'll get just at some locations bigger skips. So how to use the package correctly?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
 \markboth{#1}{}}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mcTwo}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\linespread{1.8}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Hi abdu. Could you extend your code above with an example document that gives the "very big skips" that you mention? Without that, I can only guess at what the problem might be. My guess is that LaTeX is putting extra spaces between your paragraphs, in order to fill to the bottom of each page. Try adding `\raggedbottom` to your preamble, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Spreading lines with a factor of 1.6 is a certain way to get poor typesetting. Adding a non zero parskip means having large white stripes on your page. Please, reconsider your choice and *don't* separate paragraphs with a vertical space; the indent is sufficient.

Comment: @JohnWickerson John you're a genius! Thank you, yes LaTeX was trying to full the pages. It works now =)

Comment: @egreg you mean not to sperate the paragraphs with a blank line? So how do I do it with the indent?

Comment: @abdu Just don't set `\parindent` to zero.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that LaTeX is putting extra spaces between your paragraphs, in order to fill to the bottom of each page. Try adding `\raggedbottom` to your preamble, and see if that changes anything.

As egreg says, the norm nowadays is to distinguish consecutive paragraphs by indentation, rather than by adding vertical space between them. One reason is that indentation is much more space efficient. More reasons are given by Jan Tschichold in his 1997 book *The Form of the Book: Essays on the Morality of Good Design*, on p.17:

> "The beginnings of paragraphs must be indented. Paragraphs without indent [...] are a bad habit and should be eliminated. The indention – usually one em – is the only sure way to indicate a paragraph. The eye, on reaching the end of a line, is too inert to recognize a tight exit – and in works without indents, even that frequently has to be produced as an afterthought from a flush ‘last’ line. In order of importance, legibility and clarity have to come first; a smooth contour of the typeset page is of lesser importance. Therefore, typesetting without indentions is to be dismissed as an error."